# Issue while running JWSC ant task in solaris 11 , weblogic 12c

Tags: weblogic12c

I am building webservices with JWSC ant task with weblogic 12 c
The ant build.xml performes good in windows OS and generates the war .

Am stuck in the process of running  the same in Solaris 11

In Solaris environment , the JWSC ant task starts processing and hangs up after the below step

JWSC JWS:/file.java validated

No response after this , the script hangs up there

Looking for an advice to over come this stage